# azure message delivered before ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc time

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

We are using ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc property on message to make it deliver later time (delayed). Seems azure is ignoring that property and delivering the message as soon as it is sent.

Note: I updated all packages related to service bus in application. Still no luck.

Using - Service Bus - Topic - Subscription.

```
TopicClient topicClient = TopicClient.Create(topicName);
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(serializedMessage);
brokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = scheduleDate;
topicClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
```

Comment: Update: Setting ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc for all messages (some messages with required time and some messages with DateTime.UtcNow). Now messages are waiting, but they are not getting delivered at scheduled time.

Comment: Having the same problem, I don't see why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with many, no one had faced this kind of problem. 
So instead of keeping messages in queue for long time, I am maintaining a table and have a (quartz)job to publish the message on scheduled time. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had this problem but it was due to the time on my server being slightly different to Azure's time. I was effectively asking for my message to be sent instantly instead of with a 10s delay.